# libgdx resize image on multiple screens ratio

Tags: android, libgdx

I know how to set Image width and height using pixel coords. Is there a way to set relative coords? I want to deal with multiple screens.

For example i have 1920x1080 screen size. And i have relative coords width (-100,100) and height = 200*1080/1920=112.5, height(-56.25, 56.25)

Can i use this relative coords to set width and height? and how to do it?
Is there any best practices to handle different screens ratio, handle orientation change correctly?

thanks in advance.

here is how i'm using it in my app:

create()

```
    public void create() {
         stage = new Stage();
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

            camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
            camera.setToOrtho(true, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
            camera.update();

Skin skinBackground = new Skin();
        skinBackground.add("background", new Texture(Gdx.files.absolute(FilePathSlicer.preparePath(taskSheet.background.getPicUrl()))));
        background=new Image(skinBackground,"background");

        if(background!=null) {
            background.setWidth(width);
            background.setHeight(height);
            stage.addActor(background);
        }
    }
```

render

```
public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(255/255f, 255/255f, 255/255f, 1);
        stage.getBatch().setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is what [Viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) are for. Viewport is kind on flexible are connected with a stage (which is actually something like transparency that you are adding items [buttons, labels etc...] on).

It cares for scaling in a way you defined by creating a proper type of viewport.

Main steps are:

```
    //create() method
        stage = new Stage(); //creating a stage
        viewport = new FillViewport( screenWidth, screenHeight ); //creating viewport choosing a proper Viewport class - for example Fill

        stage.setViewport( viewport ); //applying actors (buttons, labels etc...) to a stage


    //render() method
        stage.act(); //acting a stage to calculate positions of actors etc
        stage.draw(); //drawing it to render all

    //resize(width, height) method
        viewport.update(width, height); //updateing viewport that it scales in proper way
```

You have many types of vieports like just for example:

- FillViewport - stretches graphics to fill the display
- FitViewport - adding black stripes when screen is to wide
- ExtendViewport - cutting what is out of the screen

etc.

Of course you can have many stages and others viewport for each of them.

To read more about stages, actors and viewports visit: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d

---

You don't have to care about screen orientation - all you need to do is to define your app orientation in android Manifest

Comment: thanks mate. what about relative coord system? is it possible?

Comment: it will care also for position so you don't have to think about coordinates

Comment: after i use FillViewport  i get blank screen. What can be wrong?

Comment: What screen width and height have you passed? The best would be full code od Screen - you can link it here

Comment: FillViewport worked, but for some reason it moved my game to the center of the screen. I mean it moved the left bot edge to the center. I used StretchViewport as in documentation

 stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(width, height));

Comment: ok then instead of `viewport.update(width, height);` use `viewport.update(width, height, true);` - boolean at the end is for centering camera